# How to cut and save everything before first match in a string?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have some data in this format saved in a string:

`data = some-data.in.this.format`

How can I perform a cut on $data so that I am only left with some-data?

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` with `-F` (field-separator)

```
$ data=some-data.in.this.format
$ echo ${data} | awk   -F "." '{print $1}'
some-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom delimiter, in this case a dot `.` could do the trick. Try:

```
echo "data = some-data.in.this.format" | cut -d\. -f1
```

However that would return literally *everything before first match in a string*, which is literally what you asked for, so you will have:

```
data = some-data
```

Thus, if you want only to get `some-data`, I would be using:

```
echo "data = some-data.in.this.format" | cut -d\. -f1 |awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `data =`  is always going to be the first thing on the line, you can do a *substring* parameter expansion:

```
offset=7
str="data = some-data.in.this.format"
value=${str:${offset}}
echo "$value"
```

Output:

```
some-data.in.this.format
```

If both the *key* and *value* are unknown, you can split on the first `=` in the string:

```
str="data = some-data.in.this.format"

key="${str%% =*}"
value="${str#*= }"

echo "$key"
echo "$value"
```

Output

```
data
some-data.in.this.format
```

See:
`${parameter:offset}`
`${parameter#word}`
`${parameter%%word}`

at [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)